# How to write this predicate regarding trees in prolog?

Tags: prolog

I need help on defining a prolog predicate `treeMax(T,X)` that is true if `X` is the largest number stored in tree `T`, without using the "is" predicate.

I'm using function terms to represent trees : `node1(X,T)` represents a node that stores number `X` and has one child, `node2(X,T1,T2)`, and `node3(X,T1,T2,T3)`
The term `leaf(X)` represents a leaf that stores number `X`.

For example: `node2(1,leaf(1),node3(9,leaf(9),leaf(10),leaf(11)))` is a tree.

Any help is appreciate :)

Edit: The maximum number of children is 3: so the possible database are `node1(X,T)`, `node2(X,T1,T2)`, `node3(X,T1,T2,T3)`, and `leaf(X)`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but I don't think that the `leaf/1`, `node1/2`, `node2/3`, `node3/4` solution is a good one.

Develop a `maxTree/2` is simple but ...

```
treeMax(leaf(M), M).

treeMax(node1(V0, N1), M) :-
  treeMax(N1, V1),
  M is max(V0, V1).

treeMax(node2(V0, N1, N2), M) :-
  treeMax(N1, V1),
  treeMax(N2, V2),
  M is max(V0, max(V1, V2)).

treeMax(node3(V0, N1, N2, N3), M) :-
  treeMax(N1, V1),
  treeMax(N2, V2),
  treeMax(N3, V3),
  M is max(V0, max(V1, max(V2, V3))).
```

... but, as you can see, for a `node4/5` you have to develop another `treeMax` clause, another for a `node5/6`, another for a `node6/7`, usw.

Suggestion: maintain the distinction between nodes and leaf but, for nodes, implement only a struct with a value and a **list** of sub-nodes

So you have no limits in the number of subnodes; so your `maxTree/2` doesn't need to be integrated with additional clauses for a bigger number of subtrees.

So your example become

```
node(1, [leaf(1), node(9, [leaf(9), leaf(10), leaf(11)])])
```

and `maxTree/2` become

```
treeMax(leaf(M), M).

treeMax(node(V0, LN), M) :-
  treeMax(LN, V1),
  M is max(V0, V1).

treeMax([N], M) :-
  treeMax(N, M).

treeMax([Nh | Nt], M) :-
  treeMax(Nh, V0),
  treeMax(Nt, V1),
  M is max(V0, V1).
```

**--- EDIT ---**

Sorry: I see now your "without using the 'is' predicate".

It's a strange requirement but can be done.

It's very painful with your solution (`leaf/1`, `node1/2`, `node2/3`, `node3/4`); my preceding solution become

```
treeMax(leaf(M), M).

treeMax(node1(V0, N1), V0) :-
  treeMax(N1, V1),
  V1 =< V0.

treeMax(node1(V0, N1), V1) :-
  treeMax(N1, V1),
  V1 > V0.

treeMax(node2(V0, N1, N2), V0) :-
  treeMax(N1, V1),
  treeMax(N2, V2),
  V1 =< V0,
  V2 =< V0.

treeMax(node2(V0, N1, N2), V1) :-
  treeMax(N1, V1),
  treeMax(N2, V2),
  V1 >  V0,
  V2 =< V1.

treeMax(node2(V0, N1, N2), V2) :-
  treeMax(N1, V1),
  treeMax(N2, V2),
  V2 > V0,
  V2 > V1.

treeMax(node3(V0, N1, N2, N3), V0) :-
  treeMax(N1, V1),
  treeMax(N2, V2),
  treeMax(N3, V3),
  V1 =< V0,
  V2 =< V0,
  V3 =< V0.

treeMax(node3(V0, N1, N2, N3), V1) :-
  treeMax(N1, V1),
  treeMax(N2, V2),
  treeMax(N3, V3),
  V1 >  V0,
  V2 =< V1,
  V3 =< V1.

treeMax(node3(V0, N1, N2, N3), V2) :-
  treeMax(N1, V1),
  treeMax(N2, V2),
  treeMax(N3, V3),
  V2 >  V0,
  V2 >  V1,
  V3 =< V2.

treeMax(node3(V0, N1, N2, N3), V3) :-
  treeMax(N1, V1),
  treeMax(N2, V2),
  treeMax(N3, V3),
  V3 > V0,
  V3 > V1,
  V3 > V2.
```

As you can see, there is need for a `treeMax/2` clause for `leaf/1`, two clauses for `node1/2`, three clauses for `node2/3`, etc.
You need `N+1` clauses for `nodeN/N+1`.

If you use a solution based on a single `node/2` struct, with a list of subnodes, my preceding solution become

```
treeMax(leaf(M), M).

treeMax(node(V0, LN), V0) :-
  treeMax(LN, V1),
  V1 =< V0.

treeMax(node(V0, LN), V1) :-
  treeMax(LN, V1),
  V1 > V0.

treeMax([N], M) :-
  treeMax(N, M).

treeMax([Nh | Nt], V0) :-
  treeMax(Nh, V0),
  treeMax(Nt, V1),
  V1 =< V0.

treeMax([Nh | Nt], V1) :-
  treeMax(Nh, V0),
  treeMax(Nt, V1),
  V1 > V0.
```

Comment: sorry I meant that the maximum number of children is 3, and I must do it with node1, node2, node3, and leaf

Comment: @delson1337 - even so I think it's a bad idea; I've improved my answer taking in count your "without is predicate" requirment; see how more painful is the solution based on `node1/2`, `node2/3` and `node3/4`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simpler solution than the one by @max66, "folding" a `max/3` predicate over the tree. The simplification comes from using an accumulator argument to store intermediate results.

```
tree_max(Tree, Max) :-
    tree_max(Tree, 0, Max).

tree_max(leaf(N), Acc, Max) :-
    max(N, Acc, Max).
tree_max(node1(Value, Subtree), Acc, Max) :-
    max(Value, Acc, Acc1),
    tree_max(Subtree, Acc1, Max).
tree_max(node2(Value, Left, Right), Acc, Max) :-
    max(Value, Acc, Acc1),
    tree_max(Left, Acc1, Acc2),
    tree_max(Right, Acc2, Max).
tree_max(node3(Value, Child1, Child2, Child3), Acc, Max) :-
    max(Value, Acc, Acc1),
    tree_max(Child1, Acc1, Acc2),
    tree_max(Child2, Acc2, Acc3),
    tree_max(Child3, Acc3, Max).

max(A, B, Max) :-
    Max is max(A, B).
```

This implementation of `max/3` *does* use `is/2`, but (a) that's a silly artificial constraint, and (b) it's easy to rewrite `max/3` without `is/2`. The whole thing could (and should) also be generalized to a general `tree_fold/4` predicate.

Some tests:

```
?- tree_max(node2(1,leaf(1),node3(9,leaf(9),leaf(10),leaf(11))), Max).
Max = 11.

?- tree_max(node2(1,leaf(1),node3(9,leaf(9),leaf(10),leaf(7))), Max).
Max = 10.

?- tree_max(node2(1,leaf(1),node3(9,leaf(42),leaf(10),leaf(7))), Max).
Max = 42.

?- tree_max(node2(1,leaf(23),node3(9,leaf(3),leaf(10),leaf(7))), Max).
Max = 23.
```